# Create an LXC container from a local template (tar.gz)

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I'm trying to create an LXC container from a local tar.gz of a rootfs of another container but I could not find any option in lxc-create to do so. I can create a new container, remove its rootfs and replace that with my untared rootfs but this is too clumsy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found [this script](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/templates/lxc/salt_tarball) which takes a tar.gz and creates an LXC container.

```
$ lxc-create -n test-container -t ./salt_tarball -- --network_link lxcbr0 --imgtar /root/template.tar.gz
```

note here that `salt_tarball` is the name of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Using [that script](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/templates/lxc/salt_tarball) @syed mentioned above needs more work (Ubuntu 16.04, LXC 2.0, still *not* lxd):

First you have to copy the script to the template directory and make it executable

```
$ cp salt_tarball /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-salt_tarball
$ chmod +x /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-salt_tarball
```

Be sure to add lxc- in front of the name while copying.

To create the new container using the script do

```
$ lxc-create -n test-container -t salt_tarball -- --network_link lxcbr0 --imgtar /root/template.tar.gz
```

i.e. call salt_tarball without ./ and without the lxc- added above.
The option --network_link is optional.

Take care to use `--numeric-owner` when creating your tar.gz from any existing container.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to copy the script into /usr/share/lxc. Just refer to the script with its full path, or `$(pwd)/salt_tarball`